# gcp vm console ssh instance stuck on transferring metadata

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, console

Hit the `ssh` button in the instance list and it worked without issue the first time.

Every since then, it hangs on 'transferring metadata'.

No errors, just sits there spinning forever.

Comment: How long is "forever" ? It can take a few minutes

Comment: You have to provide more details, logs etc. Did you change anything in the firewall rules or vpc routes after the successfull login ? do you have OS login enabled ? Any projectwide SSH keys ? Also - some browser extension can also cause problems with connecting.

Try to do the following to get some logs:

Try to connect via ssh button, if it fails or takes over 2 minutes go to the instance details (click on the name of the VM) and click on "Serial port 1" (console) and paste last 20 lines from the log - it might provide some clues to resolve this issue.

Comment: Try also connecting from Cloud Shell or via gcloud with $ gcloud compute instances ssh {INSTANCE_NAME}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine again.  I restarted the instance.  Not sure if that was the trick.